# reuse of cursor in django

Tags: database, django

In shell interface of django `(python manage.py shell)`, I am able to resuse `cursor` object multiple times to query something, which I generate from `connection` with command

```
from django.db import connection 
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

However, when I define a cursor in a module globally and try to use it multiple times in a function, it failes after one usage. It is being closed, so I need to create it again at the beginning of the function. Why it is not working in module while it works on shell interface?

**Note:** It is not directly related with django. Django uses `Python Database API` stated [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor). However, I still do not know whether it is problem due performance issue, recreating cursors from connections before every query operation.